# Variable ranges with multiple indexes

Tags: sas

I know that if we want to refer to a range of variables with similar names, such as for instance VAR1, VAR2, VAR3... VAR150 we can just use "VAR1-VAR50". What if, however, the naming conventions for the variables are such that there are two "ranges"?

An example: suppose I have a bunch of variables VARxxyy where the 'xx' part of it takes on values from 01 to 50 and 'yy' takes on values from 01 to 75. Is there a similar way to reference all of these at once using similar syntax? I could just say:

```
VAR0101-VAR0175 VAR0201-VAR0275 ... VAR5001-var5075
```

but I feel like that's a lot of code.

Also: is there a way to make an array of all of the variables in your data set at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three main ways to have variable lists.

One is the colon, which specifies all that start with the same prefix.

```
DROP VAR:;
```

If you have control of your variables, and you know you need to drop them later, I often name them with an _ at the start to easily drop them all.

A second is to use the -- notation, which relies on variable order. So as long as the variables are side by side, anything in between is included.

```
Var0000--Var5075;
```

You can also modify this to include only numeric or character data if necessary.

```
StartVAR-numeric-EndVar;
```

These and more are outlined here:
https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2018/05/29/6-easy-ways-to-specify-a-list-of-variables-in-sas.html

Comment: this is nice to nice StartVAR-numeric-EndVar; Thanks Reeza

Answer (score 2):

Below are some variations you can use for arrays

```
  /* to mention all character or numeric variables*/

 data _null_;
 set sashelp.class;
 array one(*) _character_;
 array two(*) _numeric_;
  run;

/* variables which are in order*/

 data _null_;
 set sashelp.cars;
 array three(*) enginesize--length;
   run;

/* all the variables must belong to same type then you can use the below code*/
  data _null_;
  set old;
  array four(*) _all_;
  run;
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution below will not work in your case, because you have more than 3000 variables matching pattern var(01-50)(01-75). Still keeping it for reference.

You can get all the variable names from the sasHelp.vColumn view. Just keep in mind that the maximum length of a macro variable is 65534, therefor if you can have maximum 789 variables with length 7 or 704 variables with length 8.

```
proc SQL noprint;
    select name into :varList separated by ' '
    from sasHelp.vColumn
    where libName = 'WORK' and memName = 'YOUR_DS_NAME' and prxMatch('/^VAR(0[1-9]|[1-4]\d|50)(0[1-9]|[1-7]\d|7[0-5]$)/', strip(upcase(name)))
    ;
quit;

%put Variables: &varList;
```

Comment: You can wrap it in a macro then that would just 'stream' the values instead with a similar logic to get around the limitation.

Comment: That's a good solution, but sometimes you want to use the result in a macro code. In this case you have to make this streaming macro 100% macro code, which is possible, but is a bit tricky in SAS. When I had to implement cases where the limit could be reached, I usually checked whether the resulting length is > 65530. And if it was, I enabled some other algorithm which put the result in N macro variables which were later processed in a loop.